# How to use Relation::morphMap() for diffrent class

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel polymorphic relation. 
I have defined two morphTo relations for two purpose.
My question is that ,but when I am defining the key of Relation::morphMap() function array , then my array key is same for one case, so I want to know is there any way by which I can specify that I am defining relation for specific class.

**My first relation....**

Package.php

```
public function provider()
{
    return $this->morphTo(null, 'map_type_id', 'map_id');
}
```

Venue.php

```
public function packages()
{
    return $this->morphMany(VendorPackage::class, 'map', 'map_type_id', 'map_id');
}
```

Vendor.php

```
public function packages()
{
    return $this->morphMany(VendorPackage::class, null, 'map_type_id', 'map_id');
}
```

I want to set the key to compare with **map_type_id** so I am setting the key in service provider.

```
Relation::morphMap([
                           config('evibe.roles.planner')        => \Vendor::class,
                           config('evibe.roles.artist')         => \Vendor::class,
                           config('evibe.roles.venue')          => \Venue::class,
                       ], false);
```

**My 2nd morphTo relation**

Ticket Booking.php

```
public function provider()
{
    return $this->morphTo(null, 'map_type_id', 'map_id');
}
```

Venue.php

```
public function bookings()
{ 
    return $this->morphMany(TicketBooking::class,null,'map_type_id','map_id');
}
```

Decors.php

```
public function bookings()
{
    return $this->morphMany(TicketBooking::class,null,'map_type_id','map_id ');
}
```

Now again I have to define the morphTo in service provider because I am not using the default Model name.

so my morphTo in service providers became like this.

```
Relation::morphMap([
                           config('evibe.roles.planner')        => \Vendor::class,
                           config('evibe.roles.artist')         => \Vendor::class,
                           config('evibe.roles.venue')          => \Venue::class,
                           config('evibe.ticket_type.venues')   => \Venue::class,
                           config('evibe.ticket_type.decors')   => \Decor::class
                       ], false);
```

Now my problem is that key  **config('evibe.roles.planner')**  and **config('evibe.ticket_type.venues)** has the same value 3, so when both things is accessed by the relationship then it is throwing error, because array have same key.

So I want to ask is there any other way to define different morphMap for different relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start by defining the polymorphic relations

**First relation....**

`Package.php`

```
public function provider() {
  return $this->morphTo(null,  'map_type_id', 'map_id');
}
```

`Venue.php`

```
public function packages() {
  // you should provide the relation name, in our exemple its called `provider` as a second parameter
  return $this->morphMany(VendorPackage::class, 'provider', 'venues');
}
```

`Vendor.php`

```
public function packages() {
  // you should provide the relation name, in our exemple its called `provider` as a second parameter
  return $this->morphMany(VendorPackage::class, 'provider', 'vendors');
}
```

**Second Relation**

`TicketBooking.php`

```
public function provider() {
  return $this->morphTo(null, 'map_type_id', 'map_id');
}
```

`Venue.php`

```
public function bookings() { 
  return $this->morphMany(TicketBooking::class, 'provider', 'venues');
}
```

`Decors.php`

```
public function bookings() {
  return $this->morphMany(TicketBooking::class, 'provider', 'decors');
}
```

and register `Relation::morphMap` as

```
Relation::morphMap([
  'vendors' => \Vendor::class,
  'venues' =>  \Venue::class,
  'decors' =>  \Decor::class
]);
```